# Is there an equivalent CSS declaration to "width: auto" for <table> elements?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

I'm trying to create a <table> that doesn't exceed a certain width (let's say 500px), even with borders of any size.

Normally, if I do:

***(HTML)***

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This is a test.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

***(CSS)***

```
div {
  width: 500px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 10px solid #000;
}
```

I'm going to end up with a <table> that is 510px wide, since half of the left and right borders will end up on the outside of the <div>. What I want is a <table> that is 500px wide **total** (i.e., that doesn't exceed the width of its parent/container). So, the left and right borders would each be 10px wide, set inside the 500px-wide containing <div> - therefore the table's remaining content area would be 480px.

I can easily do this type of thing to a <div> by using the CSS declaration "width: auto." I can fake it with a table by adding an extra <div> around it that uses "width: auto" with the border set on that <div>, not the <table>.

However, I'm hoping that a more elegant solution exists (must be cross-browser). Is there one that I'm not aware of?

Comment: what xhtml declaration are you using? I think a strict declaration would result in a table of 480px (20px for borders)

Comment: @adam...the border is added to the declared width.

Comment: But there is no declared width on the table - only on the containing div, so the table + border cannot be greater than 500px as long as the box model is correct

Comment: Tables, unlike divs, don't expand the total width of the container, though. They expand as wide as need be. So, I assume the OP wants the table to fill the container, which is where the issue with border + width comes into play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the div to 480px wide and put the 10px border on it. Then set the table to 100% width

Comment: Great, simple answer! I don't know why that didn't occur to me - but that's why I post here. ;-)

Comment: sometimes the simplest answer is the hardest one to think of!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'd work, but...could you border the first (left border) and last (right border) TDs (or TR perhaps) instead of the table itself? That should give the same visual result.

Otherwise, I wouldn't lose much sleep over a wrapper DIV.

Comment: Thanks for your help, DA. Andy's answer will actually work best in my situation, but I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a cross-browser solution. The IE box model actually works the way you would want: once you declare the width of an element, that's the width, and then it subtracts from the "inner" width of the element the padding margin and border to give you the declared width.

All of the other browsers do the opposite: they set the element width to the declared width and then add the margin padding and border.

I just tested your code in IE7 and Firefox 3.5 and both appear to be 500px wide even with the 10px black border. It's the older versions of Firefox I'd worry about.